# Add entries in postgres Sql Tables using excel sheet

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having excel sheet with columns :
vehicle
vehicle id
brand
brand id
segment
model
model id
variant
variant id
service category
service category id
service
display price
actual price

and i have to enter data in 3 tables

1. sub-category having columns name, Category_id
2. service having Columns Service, sub_category_id, hsn, gst, units, discount_percentage, flag, image_path
3. service price having columns service_id, model_id, actual_price, display_price, variant_id

service prices added w.r.t. model id and variant id and there are 50k+ models (Car and Bike) are present in model table

hirarchy for vehicle :
Vehicle type (bike or car) -> Brand -> model -> variant
hirarchy for services :
service category -> sub-category -> services -> service activities / service details

please tell me how can i read data from excel and add entries in table in spring boot
I am facing issue while adding price

public static void convertExcelToListOfProduct(InputStream is) {
//        List subCategories = new ArrayList<>();

```
    try {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("data");

        int rowNumber=0;
        Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            Row row = iterator.next();
            if(rowNumber==0){
                rowNumber++;
                continue;
            }

            Iterator<Cell> cells = row.iterator();

            int cid = 0;
            double vehicleType = 0;

            ServiceSubCategory subCategory = new ServiceSubCategory();

            ServiceSubCategory savedSubCategory = null;

            Services services = new Services();

            if (cid >=0 && cid <4) {
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cells.next();

                  // mapped cell and sets to object using getter setter
            }


        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

i have tried to read data from excel and add in objects to save using repository.save method, facing issue how do i add prices which is added with respect to model and variant id with is about 50k +

Answer (score 0):

If you have 50K+ variants and models, this is more of a technical design problem to solve.

1. You need to import them in batches - you could batch them by categories or sub categories and import them in different batches.
2. Define your classes and objects clean, and use the right data structures.
3. Your DAO classes need to be transactional to ensure the product, and the variants get saved correctly.